# Separate string with comma in 2 different strings

Tags: c#

I have 2 scenarios for my string variable.

```
string qry = "A.PHONE, A.BLOODGRP"; 
or
string qry = "A.PHONE";
```

I want my final result for 1st scenario to be in 2 strings :-

```
string sort1 = "PHONE";
string sort2 = "BLOODGRP";
```

I want my final result for 2nd scenario to be in 1 string :-

```
string sort1 = "PHONE";
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split on comma and the use `Substring` to get the part you want:

```
string qry = "A.PHONE, A.BLOODGRP"; 
var result = qry.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim().Substring(2)).ToArray();
```

In the second case just use `Substring` without split.